# Simplifying nested square roots ($\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2}$)

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I guess I learned it many years ago at school, but I must have forgotten it. From a geometry puzzle I got to the solution

$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2}$

My calculator tells me that (within its precision) the result equals exactly 2, but I have no idea how to transform the calculation to symbolically get to that result.

(I can factor out one $\sqrt{2}$ from both terms, but that does not lead me anywhere, either)

Comment: Hint: $6-4\sqrt{2}=\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: ok thanks, that helps me prove it. But how do you come to this solution (or do you just know because you have seen it a lot of times)?

Comment: Simplifying such expressions is called [Denesting Nested Radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Denesting_nested_radicals). It's easy once your calculator tells you it should equal $2$, because you're left with proving $\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}=2-\sqrt{2}$, which can be done with the hint I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks (If my task would have been to prove the equation you wrote, I probably had the idea to square both sides and compare, too...) If you put that into an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: You can square both sides, prove that the squared equality holds, then note that $2-\sqrt{2}>0$. This would finish the proof. The property used here is the following: If $a,b\ge 0$ and $a^2=b^2$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by trying to simplify $\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}$. Let's assume there is some number $p+q\sqrt{2}$ for which
$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} = p + q\sqrt{2}$$
Squaring both sides gives 
$$6-4\sqrt{2} = (p + q\sqrt{2})^2 = p^2+2q^2 + 2pq\sqrt{2}$$
Comparing coefficients gives $6=p^2+2q^2$ and $-4=2pq$, i.e. $-2=pq$.

We need to solve $p^2+2q^2=6$ and $pq = -2$ simultaneously.

If $pq=-2$ then $q=-\frac{2}{p}$ and we can substitute this into $p^2+2q^2=6$. We get
\begin{eqnarray*}
p^2+2q^2 &=& 6 \\ \\
p^2 + 2\left(-\frac{2}{p}\right)^2 &=& 6 \\ \\
p^2 + \frac{8}{p^2} &=& 6 \\ \\
p^4+8 &=& 6p^2 \\ \\
p^4-6p^2+8 &=& 0 \\ \\
(p^2-2)(p^2-4) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Either $p^2-2=0$ or $p^2-4=0$, i.e. $p=\pm\sqrt{2}$ or $p=\pm 2$. The only valid solutions are $p = \pm2$ because we usually assume that $p$ and $q$ are rational numbers, i.e. fractions.

If $p=\pm 2$ then $pq=2$ gives $\pm 2q=-2$, and so $q=\mp 1$. Hence
$$p+q\sqrt{2} = \pm(2-\sqrt{2})$$

Recall that $\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} = p + q\sqrt{2}$ and since, by definition, $\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} \ge 0$ we conclude
$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} = 2-\sqrt{2}$$

Finally:
$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}} \ \ {\color{red}{+\sqrt{2}}}= 2-\sqrt{2} \ \ {\color{red}{+\sqrt{2}}} = 2$$

Answer (score 4):

Since 
\begin{align}
6-4\sqrt{2}&=4-2\cdot 2\cdot\sqrt{2}+2\\
&=(2-\sqrt{2})^2
\end{align}
Where $2-\sqrt{2}>0$, it follows 
$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}=2-\sqrt{2}$.

Then $$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}=\color{blue}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If the expression under the first radical is a perfect square, the double product $4\sqrt2$ factors as $2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt2$. Then you indeed have $6-4\sqrt2=2^2-2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt2+(\sqrt2)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{6-4\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{6-\sqrt{4^2}\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}=$$
$$\sqrt{6-\sqrt{16}\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{6-\sqrt{16\cdot2}}+\sqrt{2}=$$
$$\sqrt{6-\sqrt{32}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{6^2}-\sqrt{32}}+\sqrt{2}=$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{36}-\sqrt{32}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{4\cdot9}-\sqrt{4\cdot8}}+\sqrt{2}=$$
$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{9}-2\sqrt{8}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2\left(\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{8}\right)}+\sqrt{2}=$$
$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{8}}+\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{9}-\sqrt{8}}+1\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}+1\right)=\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2\left(\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)}+1\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}}+1\right)=
\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}+1\right)=\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}-1+1\right)=$$
$$\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2=2$$

---

EDIT:

$$\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^2}{4}}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{4}}=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}=1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Very detailed way of factoring out the $\sqrt{2}$. But I don't see how you get from $\sqrt{\frac32 - \sqrt2}$ to $1 - \frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: @mihi see my edit!

Comment: which then boils down to having to know that $3-2\sqrt2$ is $\frac{(2-\sqrt2)^2}{2}$ - which is similar enough to knowing that $6-4\sqrt2 = (2-\sqrt2)^2$, which is the problem I stated...